# Is it possible to assign a Release Version to a specific person?

Tags: tfs

I realize that TFS is meant for Continuous Delivery so the concept of assigning an entire Release Version is not a native concept.  However, we have a need to deploy a few products manually and we would like to assign the version to a specific person to deploy.  Currently I do not see an any options to associate an Assignee to a Release Version.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could disable Continuous deployment trigger, and make someone deploy the project manually. Or you could define pre-deployment approvers, to make someone check the release before deploy:

[image]